# How to stop Kendo UI dropdown from sorting alphabetically

Tags: kendo-ui

I have been given the fun job on taking on someone elses code and trying to figure it out...

I have been tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to to stop a Kendo UI dropdown from sorting alphabetically ?

```
<select id="ddlArtworkStatuses" onlyPreparedValues="true"          
readOnlyInput="true" data-bind="idNameOptions: artworkStatuses,  
comboboxSelectedValue: artworkStatusId"></select>
```

For some reason this sorts althabetically but I want it to keep the order in the datasource. I have double checked to make sure it is in the order I want.

It doesn't use the standard way of using Kendo UI and I can't find any examples anywhere of using it this way?

It binds the view to the model with this line at the top of the view I believe?

```
<!-- ko with: fabricationModel -->
```

The vm.fabrication file is this:

```
(function (app) {
    app.namespace("models");

    var resources = {
        unableToDeleteArtworkMessage: "This artwork cannot be deleted because it is linked to one or more of the following: Movements, Shows, POs. Or it has Imported Costs, Sales or Restoration Cases.",
        unableToBlankArtworkFullyMessage: "This artwork has some data that will not be blanked if you continue. This could be one or more of the following: Movements, Shows, POs, Imported Costs, Sales or Restoration Cases. Do you want to continue?",
        deleteArtworkTitle: "Delete artwork",
        blankArtworkTitle: "Blank Artwork",
        duplicateTitle: "New artwork form is pre-populated",
        duplicateMessage: "You can make changes to Fabrication form fields. Record will be created after you press save button",
        saveError: 'An error occured during artwork saving. Changes were not saved.'
    };

    app.models.FabricationModel = function (datasource) {
        var emitter = new app.events.EventEmitter(),
            self = this,
            duplicateArtwork = ko.observable(false);

        this.isNewArtwork = ko.observable(false);
        this.isActivated = ko.observable(false);
        this.showCreationInformation = ko.observable(true);

        this.wipeArtworkModel = new app.models.WipeArtworkDialogModel(datasource);
        this.internalArtworkModel = ko.observable();
        this.editCategoryModel = new app.models.EditDhCategoryModel();

      //  alert("data=" + this.artworkStatuses);

        this.isReadOnly = ko.computed(function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel()) {
                return true;
            }

            return self.internalArtworkModel().isReadOnly();
        });

        this.canSaveStudioStatusOnly = ko.computed(function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel()) {
                return false;
            }

            return self.internalArtworkModel().isUnblockStatusActive()
                   && self.internalArtworkModel().isReadOnly()
                   && self.internalArtworkModel().isStudioStatusVisible();
        });

        this.canSaveCatRaisOnly = ko.computed(function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel()) {
                return false;
            }

            return self.internalArtworkModel().isReadOnly()
                   && self.internalArtworkModel().isArchiveProvenanceWriter();
        });

        this.isNewOrDuplicating = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.isNewArtwork() || duplicateArtwork();
        });

        this.activate = function (params) {
            var id = params.id || 0;
            self.isNewArtwork(!id);

            return self.loadArtworkDetails(id);
        };

        this.isValid = function () {
            return self.internalArtworkModel() && self.internalArtworkModel().errors().length == 0;
        };



        this.loadArtworkDetails = function (id) {
            var action = self.isNewArtwork() ? datasource.artworks.getEmpty : datasource.artworks.getById;
            return action(id)
                .done(function (result) {
                    var mapper = app.mappers["fabrication"],
                        model = mapper.map(result.data);

                    self.internalArtworkModel(model);
                    self.editCategoryModel.categoryId(model.defaultDhCategoryId);
                    self.editCategoryModel.setModeAsCategoryChanging();
                    if (self.isNewArtwork()) {
                        self.editCategoryModel.setModeAsCreation();
                        self.editCategoryModel.show();
                    }

                    self.isActivated(true);
                    duplicateArtwork(false);

                    $("a#science-link").attr("href", window.location.href);
                    triggerLoadEvent();
                });
        };

        this.saveArtwork = function () {
            if (self.isValid()) {
                return saveInternal($.noop);
            }
        };

        this.editCategory = function () {
            self.editCategoryModel.show();
        };

        this.onLoad = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("load", callback);
        };

        this.onCategoryChanged = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("category-changed", callback);
        };

        this.onDelete = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("delete", callback);
        };

        this.onCreated = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("artwork-created", callback);
        };

        this.onUpdated = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("artwork-updated", callback);
        };

        this.onBlanked = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("blanked", callback);
        };

        this.saveStudioStatusInt = function () {
            return saveStudioStatusInternal($.noop);
        };

        this.saveCatRaisInt = function () {
            return saveCatRaisInternal($.noop);
        };

        this.saveStudioStatus = ko.asyncCommand({
            execute: function (complete) {
                saveStudioStatusInternal(complete);
            },

            canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
                return !isExecuting && self.canSaveStudioStatusOnly();
            }
        });

        this.saveCatRais = ko.asyncCommand({
            execute: function (complete) {
                saveCatRaisInternal(complete);
            },

            canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
                return !isExecuting && self.canSaveCatRaisOnly();
            }
        });

        this.save = ko.asyncCommand({
            execute: function (complete) {
                return saveInternal(complete);
            },

            canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
                if (!self.isValid()) {
                    showErrors();
                }

                return !isExecuting && self.isValid();
            }
        });

        function saveStudioStatusInternal(completeCallback) {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();
            triggerSaveStudioStatusEvent();
            datasource.artworks.saveStudioStatus(model.artworkId(), model.artworkStatusId(), model.studioStatusId).always(completeCallback);
        }

        function saveCatRaisInternal(completeCallback) {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();
            triggerSaveStudioStatusEvent();
            datasource.artworks.saveCatRais(model.artworkId(), model.inclusion(), model.image(), model.details(), model.crReady(), model.selectedVolume.selected.value).always(completeCallback);
        }

        this.onSaveStudioStatus = function (callback) {
            emitter.subscribe("saveStudioStatus", callback);
        };

        function triggerSaveStudioStatusEvent() {
            emitter.publish("saveStudioStatus");
        }


        this.beginArtworkDeletion = function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel().canBeBlanked) {
                jAlert(resources.unableToDeleteArtworkMessage, resources.deleteArtworkTitle);
                return;
            }

            self.wipeArtworkModel.beginArtworkDeletion(self.internalArtworkModel().artworkId());
        };

        this.beginArtworkBlanking = function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel().canBeBlanked) {
                //jAlert(resources.unableToBlankArtworkMessage, resources.blankArtworkTitle);
                app.alerts.appConfirm(resources.unableToBlankArtworkFullyMessage, resources.blankArtworkTitle, function (ok) {
                    if (ok) {
                        self.wipeArtworkModel.beginArtworkBlanking(self.internalArtworkModel().artworkId());
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            self.wipeArtworkModel.beginArtworkBlanking(self.internalArtworkModel().artworkId());
        };

        this.duplicateArtwork = function () {
            if (!self.internalArtworkModel()) {
                return;
            }

            duplicateArtwork(true);
            resetModelBeforeDuplication();
            if (self.isValid()) {
                showErrors();
            }
            jAlert(resources.duplicateMessage, resources.duplicateTitle);
        };

        function saveInternal(completeCallback) {
            var mapper = app.mappers["fabrication"];

            //alert("saving now...");

            var unmappedModel = mapper.toJS(self.internalArtworkModel());
            if (duplicateArtwork()) {
                return saveDuplicatedArtwork(unmappedModel, completeCallback);
            }

            if (unmappedModel.artworkId) {
                return updateArtwork(unmappedModel, completeCallback);
            }

            return createArtwork(unmappedModel, completeCallback);
        }

        function saveDuplicatedArtwork(model, completeCallback) {
            return datasource.artworks.duplicate(model)
                .always(completeCallback)
                .fail(function (response) {
                    jAlert(resources.saveError);
                })
                .done(function (id) {
                    triggerArtworkCreatedEvent(id);
                    duplicateArtwork(false);
                    self.showCreationInformation(true);
                });
        }

        function updateArtwork(model, completeCallback) {
            return datasource.artworks.save(model)
                .always(completeCallback)
                .fail(function (response) {
                    jAlert(resources.saveError);
                })
                .done(function (result) {
                    if (!result) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var mapper = app.mappers["fabrication"],
                        mappedModel = mapper.map(result.data);

                    triggerUpdateEvent(
                        {
                            dhCategory: mappedModel.dhCategory(),
                            refNumber: mappedModel.refNumber(),
                            computedTitle: mappedModel.computedTitle()
                        });

                    self.internalArtworkModel(mappedModel);
                });
        }

        function createArtwork(model, completeCallback) {
            return datasource.artworks.save(model)
                .always(completeCallback)
                .fail(function (response) {
                    jAlert(resources.saveError);
                })
                .done(function (id) {
                    if (id) {
                        triggerArtworkCreatedEvent(id);
                    }
                });
        }

        function triggerLoadEvent() {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();
            emitter.publish("load", {
                artworkId: model.artworkId() || 0,
                dhCategory: model.dhCategory() || "",
                refNumber: model.refNumber() || "",
                computedTitle: model.computedTitle() || "",
                isForSale: model.isForSale
            });
        }

        function triggerArtworkCreatedEvent(artworkId) {
            emitter.publish("artwork-created", artworkId);
        }

        function triggerCategoryChangedEvent() {
            emitter.publish("category-changed", {
                name: self.internalArtworkModel().dhCategoryName(),
                id: self.internalArtworkModel().dhCategoryId()
            });
        }

        function triggerDeleteEvent(e, artworkId) {
            emitter.publish("delete", artworkId);
        }

        function triggerUpdateEvent(data) {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();
            data.isCategoryChanged = model.initialCategoryId !== model.dhCategoryId();

            emitter.publish("artwork-updated", data);
        }

        function showErrors() {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();
            if (model) {
                model.errors.showAllMessages();
            }
        }

        function resetModelBeforeDuplication() {
            var model = self.internalArtworkModel();

            model.refNumber("");
            model.computedTitle("");

            model.isOnDisplay(false);
            model.isOnRestoration(false);
            model.salesStatus("Not set");

            model.creationDate("");
            model.creatorName("");

            model.isFramed(false);
            model.framedDate("");
            model.framedUserName("");
            model.framedUserInitials("");
            model.framedUserId(null);

            model.locations(null);
            model.isInsuranceComponent(false);

            model.dateWebsiteWork("");
            model.dateWebsiteReady("");
            model.dateWebsiteUploaded("");
            model.dateRemovedFromWebsite("");
            model.collectionListing("");
            model.salesStatusChangedDate("");
            model.salesStatusChangerUserInitials("");
            model.salesStatusChangerUserName("");

            self.showCreationInformation(false);
        }

        function triggerBlanked(artworkId) {
            emitter.publish("blanked", { artworkId: artworkId, flag: true });
        }

        (function () {
            self.editCategoryModel.onChanged(function (e, categoryId) {
                self.internalArtworkModel().dhCategoryId(categoryId);
                triggerCategoryChangedEvent();
            });

            self.editCategoryModel.onCancel(function () {
                if (self.isNewArtwork()) {
                    self.isNewArtwork(false);
                    app.router.back();
                }
            });

            self.wipeArtworkModel.onDelete(triggerDeleteEvent);
            self.wipeArtworkModel.onBlank(function (e, artworkId) {
                self.loadArtworkDetails(artworkId);
                triggerBlanked(artworkId);
            });
        })();
    };
})(app);
```

It also uses a mapper:

```
(function (app, ko) {
    app.namespace("mappers");
    var s = app.urls.shared,
        datasource = app.datasource;

    var mapSettings = {
        selectedMedium: {
            create: function (options) {
                return new ListModel({
                    isRemoteSource: true,
                    url: s.get('dictionaryUrl'),
                    listType: datasource.dictionaryTypes.get("medium"),
                    currentValue: options.data,
                    nobutton: true,
                    templateName: "textAreaTemplate"
                });
            }
        },

        artist: {
            create: function (options) {
                return new ListModel({
                    isRemoteSource: true,
                    url: s.get('dictionaryUrl'),
                    listType: datasource.dictionaryTypes.get("artist"),
                    currentValue: options.data,
                    onlyPreparedValues: false
                });
            }
        },

        manager: {
            create: function (options) {
                return new ListModel({
                    isRemoteSource: true,
                    url: s.get('dictionaryUrl'),
                    listType: datasource.dictionaryTypes.get("manager"),
                    currentValue: options.data,
                    onlyPreparedValues: false
                });
            }
        },

        managerStatus: {
            create: function (options) {
                return new ListModel({
                    isRemoteSource: true,
                    url: s.get('dictionaryUrl'),
                    listType: datasource.dictionaryTypes.get("managerStatus"),
                    currentValue: options.data,
                    onlyPreparedValues: false
                });
            }
        },

        selectedVolume: {
            create: function (options) {
                return new ListModel({
                    isRemoteSource: true,
                    url: s.get('dictionaryUrl'),
                    listType: datasource.dictionaryTypes.get("volume"),
                    currentValue: options.data,
                    onlyPreparedValues: false,
                    readonly: !options.parent.isArchiveProvenanceWriter(),
                    editable: options.parent.isArchiveProvenanceWriter()
                });
            }
        },

        salesStatus: {
            create: function (options) {
                var value = options.data || "Not set";
                return ko.observable(value);
            }
        },

        oldReferences: {
            create: function (options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data);
            }
        },

        copy: ['defaultDhCategoryId', "canBeDeleted", "canBeBlanked", "isForSale"],

        ignore: ["dimensions", "dimensionUnits", "selectedMediumTypes", "selectedSeries", "selectedSubSeries", "selectedAkaNames", "selectedWebSiteMediumTypes", 'selectedWebSiteCategoryIds', "locations", "hasInTransitLocations"]
    },
        unmapSettings = {
            ignore: ["selectedMedium", "artist", "manager", "managerStatus", "mediumTypesModel", "dimensionModel", "seriesModel", "subSeriesModel", "akaModel", "webSiteMediumTypesModel", "webSiteCategoriesModel", "selectedVolume"]
        },

        map = function (json) {
            var convertedObject = ko.utils.parseJson(json);

            var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(convertedObject, mapSettings);

            model.artworkStatusesModel = new ListModel({
                isRemoteSource: false,
                currentValue: convertedObject.selectedArtworkStatus,
                data: convertedObject.artworkStatuses,
                //data: filteredSalesStatuses,
                onlyPreparedValues: true,
                allowNull: false,
                readonly: true
            });


            alert("mooo=" + model.artworkStatuses()[0].name());
            alert("mooo=" + model.artworkStatuses()[1].name());
            alert("mooo=" + model.artworkStatuses()[2].name());
            //alert("mooo=" + model.artworkStatuses()[3].name());
            //alert("mooo=" + model.artworkStatuses()[4].name());

            model.dhCategoryName = ko.computed(function () {
                var categories = model.dhCategories();
                for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                    var category = categories[i];
                    if (category.id() == model.dhCategoryId()) {
                        return category.name();
                    }
                }

                return "";
            });

            model.initialCategoryId = convertedObject.dhCategoryId;
            model.dimensionModel = new app.models.DimensionModel(convertedObject.dimensions);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(convertedObject.dimensionUnits, function (unit) {
                model.dimensionModel.units.push(unit);
            });
            model.locations = ko.observable(convertedObject.locations ? {
                archivedLocations: $.map(convertedObject.locations, function (elem) {
                    return elem.isArchived ? elem : null;
                }),
                activeLocations: $.map(convertedObject.locations, function (elem) {
                    return elem.isArchived ? null : elem;
                }),
                hasInTransitLocations: convertedObject.hasInTransitLocations
            } : convertedObject.locations);
            model.mediumTypesModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedMediumTypes, { url: s.get("mediumTypesUrl") });
            model.seriesModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedSeries, { url: s.get("seriesUrl") });
            model.subSeriesModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedSubSeries, { url: s.get("subSeriesUrl") });
            model.akaModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedAkaNames, { url: s.get("akaUrl") });

            model.webSiteMediumTypesModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedWebSiteMediumTypes, { url: s.get("webSiteMediumTypeUrl") });
            model.webSiteCategoriesModel = new app.models.MultilistModel(convertedObject.selectedWebSiteCategories, { url: s.get("webSiteCategoryUrl") });
            model.isStudioStatusVisible = ko.computed(function () {
                var foundStatuses = ko.utils.arrayFilter(model.artworkStatuses(), function (status) {
                    return status.id() == model.artworkStatusId();
                });

                var currentStatus = foundStatuses[0];
                if (currentStatus) {
                    return currentStatus.name().toLowerCase() == "in progress";
                }

                return false;
            });


            addValidationOptions(model);

            return model;
        },

        toJS = function (artwork) {
            var result = ko.mapping.toJS(artwork, unmapSettings);

            result.artist = artwork.artist.toJS();
            result.manager = artwork.manager.toJS();
            result.managerStatus = artwork.managerStatus.toJS();
            result.selectedMedium = artwork.selectedMedium.toJS();
            result.selectedVolume = artwork.selectedVolume.toJS();

            result.dimensions = artwork.dimensionModel.toJS();

            result.selectedMediumTypes = artwork.mediumTypesModel.toJS();
            result.selectedSeries = artwork.seriesModel.toJS();
            result.selectedSubSeries = artwork.subSeriesModel.toJS();
            result.selectedAkaNames = artwork.akaModel.toJS();

            result.selectedWebSiteMediumTypes = artwork.webSiteMediumTypesModel.toJS();
            result.selectedWebSiteCategories = artwork.webSiteCategoriesModel.toJS();

            return result;
        };

    function isValidationRequired(model) {
        var artworkStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(model.artworkStatusId);
        var dhCategory = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(model.dhCategoryId);
        return artworkStatus == app.global.dictionary.get("compiteArtworkStatus")
            && dhCategory != app.global.dictionary.get("ignoreDHCatigory");
    }

    function addValidationOptions(model) {
        model.artworkStatusId.extend({ required: true });
        model.title.extend({ required: true });
        model.artist.selected.value.extend({ required: true });

        model.startYear.extend({
            lessEqualThan: {
                params: model.endYear,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return (model.endYear() != undefined && model.endYear() != null);
                },
                message: 'From Date should be less or equal than a To Date'
            }
        });

        model.endYear.extend({
            required: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "To Date field is required"
            }
        });

        model.selectedMedium.selected.value.extend({
            required: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "Medium is required"
            }
        });

        model.mediumTypesModel.hasValue.extend({
            equal: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "Medium Type is required"
            }
        });

        model.akaModel.hasValue.extend({
            equal: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "Aka is required"
            }
        });

        model.isInsuranceComponent.extend({
            equal: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "At least 1 Insurance component should be chosen"
            }
        });

        model.dimensionModel.hasDimensions.extend({
            equal: {
                params: true,
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return isValidationRequired(model);
                },
                message: "The Dimension fields should be filled"
            }
        });

        model.errors = ko.validation.group(model, { deep: true });
    }

    app.mappers.fabrication = {
        settings: mapSettings,
        map: map,
        toJS: toJS
    };
})(app, ko);
```

Where I have the alerts, the items are in the right order, so somewhere they are getting sorted but cant find out where?!

I hope someone can help?

It would be really appreciated.

Many thanks,
David.

Comment: By default the items in the datasource are not sorted as per this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort so if this data is being grabbed from a remote source the sorting must be being applied before it hits this control. I have provided an example showing this in action here: http://dojo.telerik.com/EkuZa

Comment: Thanks but the problem is they are using it a different way with the select as shown above, I cant find any examples of this usage anywhere? So not sure how it works?

Comment: It binds the view to the js model with this line at the top I believe? <!-- ko with: fabricationModel -->

Comment: `idNameOptions` this looks like it may be a custom binder which may be doing the sorting for you. I would suggest looking for where this code exists. My KnockOut knowledge is limited but that idNameOptions looks like a custom binder. it should be somewhere with **ko.bindingHanders.idNameOptions = {some code in here}**

Comment: Ok thanks, I found this:  ko.bindingHandlers.idNameOptions = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var options = valueAccessor();
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { options: options, optionsText: "name", optionsValue: "id" });
        }
    };

Comment: But I still cannot see where the sorting is occurring? Does it occur in the applyBindingsToNode function somehow?

Comment: As I said my knowledge of KO is limited at best. My advice would be hit `breakpoints`/ `console log statements` at various points of the data being used (from initial load all the way through to be being bound and beyond if required) to see how and  at which point the data is being manipulated from the original load order (if that is being loaded in correctly)

Comment: Ok thanks, I have tried that already but still couldn't find where the sort was being applied. Bloody ridiculous so much effort just to change the order of the items in a dropdown! Things like this really put me off Kendo, had similar issues in the past, something that should take 5 mins, takes days or weeks if at all! lol

Comment: Can do sorting when using DataSource but not when using BindTo???